# pipe() followed by write() throws "Bad file descriptor" error

Tags: c, pipe

I'm not sure if this is trivial or an incorrect understanding of the whole pipe() function. Here is the smallest version of my problem.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {

    int socket[2], r, buff[512];
    const char* msg = "what is wrong with pipes";

    r = pipe(socket);
    if(r < 0) perror("pipe()");

    r = write(socket[0], msg, sizeof(*msg));
    if(r < 0) perror("write()");

    r = read(socket[1], buff, sizeof(*msg));
    if(r < 0) perror("read()");

    return 0;
}
```

This program always generates the following output when compiled under Linux, on gcc 9.2.1

```
write(): Bad file descriptor
read(): Bad file descriptor
```

What exactly is the code problem here? I do understand that it is supposed to be used in the IPC setup with multiple processes. But, why wouldn't this code work? I don't see any obvious mistakes from my reading of man on pipe & pipe2, write and read.

Comment: As per `man 2 pipe`, it appears you `write` to the read-only fd, and `read` from the write-only fd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to swap `[0]` and `[1]`.  `[1]` is the write end, `[0]` the read end.

Comment: See also [man pipe](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe): "*pipefd[0] refers to the read end of the pipe. pipefd[1] refers to the write end of the pipe.*"

Answer (score 3):

Suggest reading/understanding the MAN pages for the C library functions you use:  [man for pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)

from the pipe(2) man page:

```
pipe()  creates  a pipe, a unidirectional data channel that can be used
   for interprocess communication.  The array pipefd is used to return two
   file  descriptors  referring to the ends of the pipe.  pipefd[0] refers
   to the read end of the pipe.  pipefd[1] refers to the write end of  the
   pipe.   Data  written  to  the write end of the pipe is buffered by the
   kernel until it is read from the read end of the pipe. 
 For further details, see pipe(7).
```

Notice, especially:

**pipefd[0] refers to the read end of the pipe.**

and

**pipefd[1] refers to the write end of the pipe.**

Comment: I took the anology of a "pipe" a little too literally I guess. Thanks.